# How to integrate Finger print authentication in Ionic 6 - Did not found any valid plugin in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, fingerprint, ionic6

I'm looking to integrate device finger print authentication to my Ionic 6 mobile app. But I could not see any working plugins regarding to this.
Please provide me any working plugins for this, If any one has implemented.
Thanks in Advance.

Tried - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio
But no use

Answer (score 0):

[Identity Vault](https://ionic.io/docs/identity-vault) in combination with [Auth Connect](https://ionic.io/docs/auth-connect) will do the trick. One thing of note is that these are premium (paid for) plugins. But, you can get started for free to see if it will work for you first.